# Is there any risk to using Crossover instead of natively running Windows (e.g. via Bootcamp)?

Tags: windows

In short, I basically want to run a few pieces of Windows specific software (ironically emulators) on a Mac. Instead of natively running Windows (e.g. via. Bootcamp) I was intending to go the CrossOver route as I know that all the pieces of software run via. it cleanly.

https://www.codeweavers.com/products

In short I had a thought though, am I opening myself up to risks by emulating a Windows environment effectively (without doing the Bootcamp thing) on my clean Mac?

I'm figuring others have done this (either via. CrossOver or Bootcamp) What are the risks?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: You said, "Instead of emulating Windows (e.g. via. Bootcamp)", well running Windows natively on a Mac via setting it up using Boot Camp Assistant is not at all emulating Windows!

Comment: @user3439894 cool thanks. Didn't understand the process. Think I need to re-title this but I am assuming there are risks however I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Crossover Office to run a couple of Windows programs on your Mac usually works quite well, **IF** the program is specifically supported by Crossover. If it is not *specifically* supported it may work but some features may not, it might crash, etc.

Not sure what you mean by "risks." Though I don't use Crossover Office (or the open source that it is based on: Wine) it emulates part of the Win32 API allowing Windows programs to run outside of Windows.

This **may** be safer than running Windows in a virtual machine (Parallels or the free Virtualbox) as you don't have the whole Windows environment that may need continuous updating/patching or even it's own virus checker.

But generally speaking I have heard that Crossover Office is a reasonably well working app that does what it advertises with minimal issues.

Comment: Thanks I think this tells me what I need & I will go the Crossover route as I know the programmes that I want to use work reasonably well with it. By risks meant viruses. I use Intego & Clam with the Mac OSX, & just had concerns with what I may open myself up to by creating a "live" Windows environment.